# Не отображает View после программного добавления во ViewGroup

Tags: java, android

Я добавляю во `FrameLayout` программно несколько вьюшек(`ImageView`)

```
public class PixelGridView extends FrameLayout {
...
     public void addViewWithoutCoords(ImageView view, int column, int row) {
            float x = column * mCellSideSize;
            float y = row * mCellSideSize;

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                view.setLayoutParams(lp);

            view.setLeft(0);
            view.setTop(0);

            view.setX(x);
            view.setY(y);
            view.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            addView(view);
        }
...
}
```

и после добавления они не отображаются, хотя они есть и `getChildCount()` возвращает их кол-во. `getVisibility()` на них возвращает 0 (`VISIBLE`)

после этого в этот `FrameLayout` можно драг'н'дропать вьюшки и после первого дропа отображаются все разом (и те, которые не отображались)

Никак не пойму что может быть не так, уже и перегуглил, но ничего подобного не находил.

EDIT

вызов метода для добавления (сейчас `TableView` это `RelativeLayout`)

```
    TableView tableView = new TableView(getActivity());
    ((ImageView)tableView.findViewById(R.id.ivTable)).setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), getTableResId(hallTable.type)));
tableView.setOnTouchListener(new PlaceDragListener.TableTouchListener());
mPixelView.addViewWithoutCoords(tableView, hallTable.column, hallTable.row);
```

и разметка для `TableView`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivTable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/table_4"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ivTableName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/style_table_grey"
        android:text="12"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

теперь вьюшки показывает почти сразу как только начинаю драгать новые вьюшки (не те, которые добавил программно изначально) в этот контейнер (`FrameLayout`). не пойму какой метод оно может вызывать что оно отображает их

Comment: Попроубуйте `invalidate()` на `FrameLayout` вызвать после добавления вьюхи

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сразу это попробовал, но не показывает. никак не вижу что я упускаю, вроде при дропе так же добавляется вьюшка и перерисовка отрабатывает

Comment: покажите как и куда кладете

Comment: @АндроидАндроид обновил вопрос